# Как использовать один репозиторий для нескольких не связанных проектов

Tags: java, github

**Необходимо** использовать один репозиторий github для нескольких разных проектов.
С первым из проектов вопросов не возникало, но при создании второго, мне не удается запушить его в репозиторий, идея говорит сперва сделать pull, но после этого в новый проект скачивается все содержимое репозитория, а оно мне не нужно.
Нужно добавить новый проект как новую папку в репозитории, по сути, не связанную с другими папками/проектами.

Comment: Под каждый проект надо делать в таком случае свою ветку и переключатсья уже по веткам

Comment: Для разных несвязанных между собой проектов лучше делать отдельные репозитории.

Comment: может gitmodules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удобнее в разных ветках!
Перед тем, как запушить, выбираете ту папку, которую необходимо!

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант: делаем в разных ветках.

Второй вариант: делаем в разных папках и локально храним разные варианты gitignore, чтобы скрывать спуленную другую папку.